# How to troubleshoot random hangs / pauses?

Tags: debugging

Short of building a debug version of emacs and adding break points.

Whats the best way to know whats happening during a 'pause' while emacs runs? *(assuming the pause is long enough to manually run an operation)*

Is there a way to press Ctrl-C in the terminal to get a stack trace or something similar?

Comment: Ended up having to use `gdb` with a debug emacs, problem was eldoc running command that took a long time.

Answer (score 1):

`toggle-debug-on-quit` is designed for this purpose.

> (toggle-debug-on-quit &optional INTERACTIVELY)
>
> Toggle whether to enter Lisp debugger when C-g is pressed.
>   In an interactive call, record this option as a candidate for saving
>   by "Save Options" in Custom buffers.

When you press `C-g` is will break the running code and display the stack trace.  From there you can examine the state of execution and cancel/resume execution.

You can enable/disable it by `M-x toggle-debug-on-quit` or through the menu bar `Options > Enter Debugger on Quit/C-g`.

Comment: This is a good solution and I did try it, as it happened in my particular case, it didn't help in finding the root cause of the problem *(a hanging external process)*.

Comment: @ideasman42 Ah.  In cases like that you might find [strace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strace) helpful.

Comment: Ah, I've used strace, but didnt think to apply to this problem - thanks.